# batch file is not called from within VBS file when run using Task Scheduler in windows 2008R2

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have created a vbs file that calls a batch file which works perfectly when run manually.
When I run the same vbs script from the scheduled tasks, however, the vbs completes without error but it seems the batch file is not called because none of the taks it is responsible for are done.

I have made sure that the scheduled task runs under my administrator account. I have had quite a lot of experience running this same taks on an older server but I have recently migrated to a new 2008 R2 from 2003.

Here is the line that does not execute:

```
wshell.run "%comspec% /c ""C:\My Scripts\ForAdministration\AddSitesScripts\AddSite.bat"" " & DomainName & " " & WebsiteID & " " & DomainName20 & " " & Path & " " & HasStats & " " & NewAppPool & " " & 1 & " " & 1 & " " & 1, 0, True
```

I log all of the variables to a text file and they are fine. As i said this runs fine when triggered manually.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your 2008 R2 machine is a 64 bit system, and %comspec% specifies the 64 bit version of CMD.exe.
Most likely you want to use the 32 bit version of CMD.exe (YES, there are two!).
Change %comspec% to

```
%SystemRoot%\sysWOW64\cmd.exe
```

Yes... that is right!  The CMD.exe in sysWOW64 is the 32 bit version!

Comment: Thanks. My Environment variable is showing the following for Comspec, C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe. Wouldn't I get the same result running manually if the version was incorrect? I appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Probably being run as a different user in a scheduled task.

Verify that the user has the necessary permissions.

Verify that the problem is not due to an assumed current directory.

Put the following statement as the first line in the bat file and try running both ways (manual and scheduled):

```
echo.CD=%cd% & pause
```

Note that the current directory gets change when you 'Run as administrator'.  You can resolve that by adding the following line at the top of your program (to set the desired CD before referencing any files/folders).

```
pushd %~dp0
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but since I am specifying the direct path to the file, shouldn't that suffice?